# "Picture Size" column in SharePoint Online document library

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have a folder containing images in a SPO document library. I would like to create a column showing the dimensions of each image in pixels like so

| Title | Picture Size |
| --- | --- |
| Image_1.jpg | 1920x1080 |
| Image_2.png | 800x600 |

The info is available, when I click on 'details' and the scroll all the way down past "More details", which shows "Dimensions". I've spent the better part of a day search for a way to acces this information in a column, but no luck!

Does anyone know how to get a proper Picture Size column?

Answer (score 1):

The default document library has no Picture Size column.

As a workaround, you could use picture library to store pictures.

Go to home page -> New -> App -> Classic experience -> Picture library.

In the picture library, choose List view.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. We have an elaborate folder structure and only some folders contain images. It would be very impractical to move these folders out of the structure. Frankly I'm amazed such a feature is missing from the standard 'modern' experience in a document library.

Comment: You could make the suggestion in the feedback portal to improve the user experience. https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/